# Using javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a shopping website and I am using javascript to add items to cart. Every time I click on add to cart, it puts the name of the item in a div that represents the cart. I would like to keep the content of the cart on each page, so what I did is:

```
$("#cartlink").attr("href", "cart.php?app="+tab+"")
```

Where "tab" is an array containing all the items in the cart. I then use a GET to retrieve the elements of the cart on the cart.php page. But my problem is since I add items in the cart using JS, if the user changes page without clicking on the cart.php?app link, tab will be erased and I have no way to recover "tab". If the user clicks on the cart.php link, I can use a GET and store the content into a session and then use it on every page.

So I would need a way to memorize the cart content if the user decides not to click cart.php.

Thanks!

Comment: SESSION, cookies, or local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store the cart status in JavaScript, and submit it to the server when the user confirms the order.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a plugin such as http://www.jstorage.info/

it will give you an easy way to store/retrieve your data on the client side

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you're doing, but it sounds like you could just bind a listener to the window's `beforeunload` event, which is called before the page is unloaded (location changes). This is how websites (pop-up ads) achieve the "are you sure you want to leave" dialog.

An example:

```
window.document.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
  $.ajax({ url: '/saveCart.php', data: tab, 
      success: function(){
      }, 
      error: function(data) { 
      }
    });
}, false);
```

Note that since you can't cancel a `beforeunload` event, it might be safer to just update cookies instead of making an ajax call, since if the HTTP request fails for some reason, the page will still continue to unload. [Here's a really good primer on setting cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

A really really simple solution would just be to return a string in the `beforeunload` listener, which would create a confirm dialog that could say something like "your cart will not be saved. Please save by clicking 'save cart'", etc. Not the best UX though.